# Connection pooling in Netty

Tags: netty

I'm trying to build a reverse proxy with Netty, and I'd like to keep a pool of open sockets to the backend servers, instead of every incoming socket requiring a new socket from the reverse proxy to a backend server.

Can you do this with Netty? How?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, answering my own question, there is a nice example how to do this in the [LittleProxy](http://www.littleshoot.org/littleproxy/) source code.  In particular, in HttpRequestHandler.java, follow the usage of [endpointsToChannelFutures](http://www.littleshoot.org/littleproxy/xref/org/littleshoot/proxy/HttpRequestHandler.html#47).

Comment: Looks like the code has been updated and endpointsToChannelFutures renamed to externalHostsToChannelFutures.